# Nombre que recibe la filigrana al final de los nombres en las firmas

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

En mis investigaciones genealógicas me he dado cuenta de que, en los documentos históricos, las firmas de las personas en las actas notariales (y otros documentos) consistían en el nombre de la persona, rematado por una especie de filigrana. Véanse los siguientes ejemplos, extraídos de documentos de 1834:

[image: Firma de Raimunda Porcel]

[image: Firma de Miguel Porcel]

Incluso en firmas más elaboradas:

[image: Firma de Antonio Francisco de Martos y Ossorio]

Al final del nombre, tras *Ossorio*, aparece la filigrana mencionada.

¿Qué nombre tienen (o tenían) esas filigranas que se dibujaban tras el nombre en las firmas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿No es una [rúbrica](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%BAbrica)?

> 1. f. Rasgo o conjunto de rasgos, realizados siempre de la misma manera, que suele ponerse en la firma después del nombre y que a veces la sustituye.

Comment: Ostras, pues eso parece. Para mí _rúbrica_ era sinónimo de _firma_, pero ya veo que es más que eso.